# Copy from page 2 to last cell

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

Ok so this is hard to explain, Will be better if I show you.

I'm pulling data from page 2 - Cells A & B

Each time the amount of rows will be different so I'm trying to make a Macro copy the cells from a pre-made box on page one to the end of the row on page 2.

Say on page 2 the rows stop at 25, I only want it to copy 25x on page 1

Here's how it looks, and if I highlight the box's then put the mouse at the bottom right I can drag it down and it copies it for me.. This is what I'm trying to make the macro do.

However, I don't know what to use for my Macro?!

[image]

```
Sub Test()'

    Range("G2:J3").Select
    Range("J3").Activate
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:J5"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("G2:J5").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Um... I'm confused. You want to populate certain amount of cells using autofill, am I right? If so, your code starting from `Selection.Autofill` does the job. What it your problem then?

Comment: @lowak I have two pages, 
1) list - Cells A & B
2) with the bar code (picture above)

I'm pulling the data from 2 to 1.

I'm wanting a macro that'll copy the barcode box (in picture) down until theres no more data left from page 1 so I'm no left with any blank box's... ?

Comment: Two pages, do you mean sheets?

Comment: @lowak yes, Sorry please see my edit.

Comment: So still I don't know what is your problem? Is it about copying from one sheet to another?

Comment: @lowak Its pulling data from sheet 2 as you can see in the formula bar.
on sheet 2 i have (example) 30 columns of data.
on sheet 1 i have that one box as a template

I want to copy/duplicate that box down 30 times, BUT if it goes down 31 times then I'll have 1 box with blank data.

Comment: Ok, how can I know you need to copy it 30 times not 31?

Comment: @lowak I've uploaded a example here http://www.sendspace.com/file/y4wsub

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to work out, How can I make the macro so it copyies to last row..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so starting from LastCell thing, here you got some information about it: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LastCell.aspx

It was not so easy, because you have merged cells so I had to make a little workaround. First step I am counting number of cells in Worksheets `List` from your example. Later I am using autofill to fill as many cells as needed - columns G:I and copying formats in the same Cells in column J. Last step is to copy values from column J.

It's kinda strange but it is all thanks to merged cells ;)

Hope it works.

```
Sub counting()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("List") 'your worksheet name
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
End With

Worksheets("Barcodes").Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(3, 9)).AutoFill _
Destination:=Range(Cells(5, 7), Cells(6 + (LastCellRowNumber * 2) - 4, 9)), Type:=xlFillDefault 'filling columns from G to I
Worksheets("Barcodes").Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(3, 10)).AutoFill _
Destination:=Range(Cells(5, 10), Cells(6 + (LastCellRowNumber * 2) - 4, 10)), Type:=xlFillFormats ' filling with format J column

j = 4
k = 5

For i = 6 To LastCellRowNumber 'filling values in column J

    Cells(j, 10).Value = "=List!A" & i
    Cells(k, 10).Value = "=List!B" & i

    j = j + 2
    k = k + 2

Next

End Sub
```

Editted code version 2:

```
Sub counting()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("List") 'your worksheet name
With WS
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
End With

Worksheets("Barcodes").Range(Cells(5, 7), Cells(6, 7)).AutoFill _
Destination:=Range(Cells(5, 7), Cells(6 + (LastCellRowNumber * 2) - 4, 7)), Type:=xlFillDefault 'filling column G

Worksheets("Barcodes").Range(Cells(5, 8), Cells(6, 9)).AutoFill _
Destination:=Range(Cells(5, 8), Cells(6 + (LastCellRowNumber * 2) - 4, 9)), Type:=xlFillFormats 'filling with columns H:J

j = 7
k = 8

For i = 3 To LastCellRowNumber 'copying values in columns I, J

    Cells(j, 9).Value = "=List!A" & i
    Cells(j, 8).Value = Cells(j - 2, 8).Value
    Cells(k, 9).Value = "=List!B" & i
    Cells(k, 8).Value = Cells(k - 2, 8).Value

    j = j + 2
    k = k + 2

Next

End Sub
```

Edition v3:

```
Sub auto_copy()

Dim WSL As Worksheet, WSB As Worksheet
Dim first_col As Long, second_col As Long
Dim first_r As Byte, first_c As Byte
Dim second_r As Byte, second_c As Byte
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long, comeback As String
Dim LastCell As Range, ActiveWS As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveWS = ActiveSheet.Name

Set WSB = Worksheets("Barcodes") 'your worksheet name
Set WSL = Worksheets("List") 'your worksheet name
With WSL
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row - 3
End With

first_col = Round(LastCellRowNumber / 2)
second_col = LastCellRowNumber - first_col

first_r = 5 'position of "first column" row
first_c = 7 'position of "first column" column
second_c = 11 'position of "first column" column

WSB.Activate

comeback = ActiveCell.Address

For i = 1 To LastCellRowNumber

    If Application.IsOdd(i) = True Then

    WSB.Range(Cells(first_r, first_c), Cells(first_r + 1, first_c)).Copy
    WSB.Range(Cells(first_r + 2, first_c), Cells(first_r + 1 + 2, first_c)).PasteSpecial
    WSB.Range(Cells(first_r, first_c + 1), Cells(first_r + 1, first_c + 2)).Copy
    WSB.Range(Cells(first_r + 2, first_c + 1), Cells(first_r + 1 + 2, first_c + 2)).PasteSpecial

    Else

    WSB.Range(Cells(first_r, second_c), Cells(first_r + 1, second_c)).Copy
    WSB.Range(Cells(first_r + 2, second_c), Cells(first_r + 1 + 2, second_c)).PasteSpecial
    WSB.Range(Cells(first_r, second_c + 1), Cells(first_r + 1, second_c + 2)).Copy
    WSB.Range(Cells(first_r + 2, second_c + 1), Cells(first_r + 1 + 2, second_c + 2)).PasteSpecial

    first_r = first_r + 2

    End If

Next

Range(comeback).Activate

Worksheets(ActiveWS).Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting the error 'this operation requires the merges cells to be identically sized' in the middle bit of the code :(

Comment: When you debug which part is colored yellow?

Comment: Worksheets("Barcodes").Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(3, 9)).AutoFill _
Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(3 + (LastCellRowNumber * 2) - 4, 9)), Type:=xlFillDefault 'filling columns from G to I -- I think I know why. On the example template I sent you I changed it a little. The 'barcode' is no longer in G2 its now in G5

Comment: Yes, that is the issue. All you have to do is fit the position of G2 to G5. I will edit it for you and try it.

Comment: Look I changed it a little. Now all I need to do is get it working on the other side (K5 - M6) ohhh dear :(

Comment: I'm now getting error "AutoFil method of Range class failed" highlighting same bit of code =/

Comment: Hm... strangely everything works at your example sheet. Maybe your sheet looks differently now?

Comment: Yes, I've updated it.. Added something at the top so they're moved down a little now to different ranges. If you look above I've added a screenshot & new ranges.

Comment: One clarification: merged cells are now in range G5:G6, right?

Comment: Yes, They're now G5:G6

Comment: & one more thing, It doesn't copy the prefix in the table it just puts data over it.. in say H5 & H6 it says 'Pallet:' & 'User:' so the people reading know what they are.. its just puting data into each cell

Comment: Works perfectly :D ... Now, Any help on getting it todo the same on the other side? Linked cells K5 & K6 :D

Comment: Well all you need to do is put copy/paste this code and suit to the cells. Useful hint: method `Cells()` points at cells directly via RowColumn. It means when I type `Cells(5,5)` it points at cell E5. So all you need to do is change numbers. As one of the Excel trainers said "Excel is pretty easy programming language to someone who knows english a little bit" :)

Comment: Thank you so much !!! After looking, I no longer need the second side (yours puts it all onto one side) even though it would have saved space on paper but this is fine ! Thank you :D

Comment: @Jacko058 Well there is also one more way if want to be ecofriendly and use less paper. If there is more than some number (let's say 15) then it can automatically start populate from K5:K6

Comment: That would be very useful! Do you have an updated code I could test?

Comment: Well... two things. 1. How many barcodes fit for one column? 2. If you have more barcodes that exceeds 1 sheet of paper, what then?

Comment: @Jacko058 I tried to approach the problem a little bit different, you can try it.

Comment: just tried it on one of my macro's and it works flawlessly ! Thankyou so much!